# How to overload a function when you only need to change a parameter data type

Tags: vb.net

I have a function `SelectNext()` that takes a collection parameter (of type `IEnumerable`) and it selects the next item in the collection and return that item.

```
'BaseListTypes is an Enum
Function SelectNext(listType As BaseListTypes, lst As IEnumerable(Of Object)) As Object
    Dim res As Object

   'function body here....

    Return res
End Function
```

The above function works great for any List(Of T) where T is an object or string.

However it fails when I pass it a `List(Of My_STRUCTURE)` (custom structure I have, which contains 3 string variables)

Obviously since Structure is like integer and other base types are a value types.
While objects are reference types. I can see why I am getting an error at runtime.

My question is, is there a better way than just overloading my function into something like:

```
Function SelectNext(listType As BaseListTypes, lst As IEnumerable(Of My_STRUCTURE)) As Object
```

Comment: You could use the generic interface implementation: `Function SelectNext(Of T)(listType As BaseListTypes, lst As IEnumerable(Of T))`, but you'll have to implement GetEnumerator(). Or you might define a `Class MyObject which Implements IEnumerable(MyObject)` but you'll have to implement GetEnumerator()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with generic impelementation like `SelectNext<T>`

```
class Program
{
    Program()
    {
        //SelectNext_Old(new List<object>(0));  it works 
        //SelectNext_Old(new List<Point>(0));   id doesn't work

        SelectNext(new List<object>(0));
        SelectNext(new List<Point>(0));
    }

    public object SelectNext_Old(BaseListTypes listType, IEnumerable<object> lst)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public object SelectNext<T>(BaseListTypes listType, IEnumerable<T> lst)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I dont know VB but I guess you can get the idea!

Comment: You are a genious! Thanks man! just for the VB guys, here is the function signature: `Function SelectNext(Of T)(listType As BaseListTypes, lst As IEnumerable(Of T)) As T` and to Use it, there is nothing special, just call `.SelectNext(BaseListTypes.PointsList, List(Of MyStructure).AsEnumerable)`

Comment: Thanks for vb version of it!

Comment: Thanks for the VB version. I couldn't get it to work with `BaseListTypes` but the signature `SelectNext(Of T)(lst As IEnumerable(Of T))` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, this should work for any type, whether it be reference type or value type:

```vb
Function SelectNext(Of T)(listType As BaseListTypes, lst As IEnumerable(Of T)) As T
    Dim res As T
   'function body here....

    Return res
End Function
```

I'd need more information to know for sure though.  Your question is actually a bit vague.  For one thing, what does "selects the next item in the collection" actually mean?  You should edit your question to make it more complete, with a better description of what you're doing and what errors occur and where.

Comment: Just saw your answer, this is the right answer (Thanks to Daniel for pointing out the T baby) had heck of a time finding the VB syntax though. Thanks for the answer too